# Clang does not find headers when `-stdlib=libc++`

Tags: clang, libc++

My installation of Clang works expected when using `-stdlib=libstdc++`, which is the default:

```
$ clang++ -v -stdlib=libc++ helloworld.cpp
Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
Found CUDA installation: /usr/lib/cuda, version 11.5
 "/usr/lib/llvm-14/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name helloworld.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -pic-is-pie -mframe-pointer=all -fmath-errno -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -mllvm -treat-scalable-fixed-error-as-warning -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/home/username/simplefem -resource-dir /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/backward -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/home/username/simplefem -ferror-limit 19 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o /tmp/helloworld-719bf3.o -x c++ helloworld.cpp
clang -cc1 version 14.0.0 based upon LLVM 14.0.0 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/backward
 /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/ld" -pie -z relro --hash-style=gnu --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o a.out /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/llvm-14/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib /tmp/helloworld-719bf3.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtendS.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

But it does not work anymore when I am trying `-stdlib=libc++`:

```
$ clang++ -v -stdlib=libc++ helloworld.cpp
Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
Found CUDA installation: /usr/lib/cuda, version 11.5
 "/usr/lib/llvm-14/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name helloworld.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -pic-is-pie -mframe-pointer=all -fmath-errno -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -mllvm -treat-scalable-fixed-error-as-warning -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/home/username/simplefem -resource-dir /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/home/username/simplefem -ferror-limit 19 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o /tmp/helloworld-8a27e2.o -x c++ helloworld.cpp
clang -cc1 version 14.0.0 based upon LLVM 14.0.0 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
helloworld.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'array' file not found
#include <array>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

How do solve this issue? I hope it is merely about installing the right package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system is Ubuntu when you install `clang` it will not install `libc++-dev` package by default with it, so install it by `apt install libc++-dev` and everything will work fine

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting `clang` would also install its related standard library implementation with it rightaway.